# Measuring String Size in Xamarin Forms (Android)

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

In my application, I have a button with a fixed with (currently, 100). Given a string value, I am attempting to set the font size of this button so that the entire string fits on one line.

I have created a custom button along with a renderer for this button. I have the following code in the `OnSizeChanged` method of the renderer.

```
var textView = new TextView(Context);

textView.TextSize = 10.0f;

var bounds = new Rect();

textView.Paint.GetTextBounds(text, 0, text.Length, bounds);

var size = bounds.Width() / Resources.DisplayMetrics.ScaledDensity;
```

From some trial and error work, I know that the string will barely fit within the button if I set the font size of the button to be 10.0. However, the code above reports that the size (width) of the string for a font size of 10.0 is about 70.85 (for my device). This doesn't seem to compute as it is much less than what I expected (I would have expected it to be somewhere around 95.0).

What am I missing / doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try  `TextViewCompat`.In this way, you don't have to calculate the exact size.
You can try the following code:

```
var nativeControl = Control;
nativeControl.SetMaxLines(1);

TextViewCompat.SetAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults(nativeControl, TextViewCompat.AutoSizeTextTypeUniform);
TextViewCompat.SetAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration(nativeControl, 1, 18, 1, (int)ComplexUnitType.Sp);
```

**The result :**

[image]

**Note:**

1.Above image,the First Button is the common Button,the second Button is the custom Button using `ButtonRenderer`.

2.When we check document [TextViewCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/TextViewCompat),we will find method `SetAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration` :

```
setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration(TextView textView, int autoSizeMinTextSize, int autoSizeMaxTextSize, int autoSizeStepGranularity, int unit)
```

Parameter 1 is the TextView that needs to dynamically change the font size, parameter 2, 3 and 4 are the minimum font size, maximum font size and scaling granularity, and parameter 5 is the units of parameters 2, 3 and 4, such as sp, dp, px, etc.

And we can adjust parameter: `autoSizeMinTextSize` and `autoSizeMaxTextSize` to adjust different screens.